# How to change package destination folder in CPack?

Tags: build-process, cmake

I have a multiple module *CMake* project with a root *CMakeLists.txt* with multipe *add_subdirectory* macros.

As far as I understand the default for CPack/CMake is to create package in project root folder, where root *CMakeLists.txt* resides. I would like to create a separate *install* module, with its own folder and create packages there? How to do this?

Comment: It seems CPack's `make package_source` only packs everything under CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR. No way to make it use another folder if you want to call it from a separate module :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `CPACK_TOPLEVEL_TAG` and the `CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME` variables in the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:CPackConfiguration).

Comment: CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME works for me, CPACK_TOPLEVEL_TAG don't. Thank you very much!

Comment: CPACK_TOPLEVEL_TAG is just supposed to create additional "packagename" directory. It seems that's the default behavior.

Answer (score 8):

To get the created packages in the "packages" subdirectory of your build directory, use:

```
SET(CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_PREFIX packages)
```

Comment: This **might** seem to work, but it does not.

Setting `CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_PREFIX` makes the `-B` argument of the `cpack` command unusable with CMake v3.21.0.

If `CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_PREFIX` is set and `-B` is provided, the intermediate `_CPack_Packages` directory is created in the directory specified by `-B`, but the final package files (and also checksum files) are still created in the directory specified by `CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_PREFIX`.

Refer to https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22842 for details.

Answer (score 7):

Use the CPack variable [`CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html#variable:CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY).

Example:

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Packaging")
```

Do **not** use the non-documented variable `CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_PREFIX` as suggested in one of the answers. It makes the `-B` argument of the `cpack` command unusable (tested with CMake v3.21.0).

Also note that the variables `CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME` and `CPACK_TOPLEVEL_TAG` mentioned in the accepted answer are unrelated to the package (output) directory used by CPack.

Comment: I've created an issue on the CMake issue tracker: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22842