# Cpack headers folder destination

Tags: linux, cmake, rpm, cpack

I need to locate all headers from my library not to `/usr/include` but `/usr/include/mylibname` . Please notice that I want to change location of headers. My `.so` file I want to keep in `/usr/lib` folder

I tried this:
[How to change package destination folder in CPack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219128/how-to-change-package-destination-folder-in-cpack) but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. Actually it is not my library. There was a line
`install (FILES ${CORE_HDRS} DESTINATION include )`

so you can fixed it in this way `install (FILES ${CORE_HDRS} DESTINATION include/mylibname)`